# Finding a simpler solution in R

Tags: r

In package alr4, is a data frame, "Mitchell" with two columns, one being month number, the other being temperature for that month. The months are denoted 0, 1, 2, 3... 203 (representing Jan, Feb, Mar, ...Dec) where month 12 is January of the following year. I'm trying to make a data frame which in the months column has 1, 1, 1, ... 2, 2, 2,... grouping the months together and the temperature column is a re-ordering of the above going 0, 12, 24,... 1, 13, 25, ...

I decided to make the two columns separately then use cbind to join them together:

```
#Making temperature column
NTemp <- subset(Mitchell$Temp, Mitchell$Month %% 12 == 0)
for(i in 1:11) {
  dummy <- subset(Mitchell$Temp, Mitchell$Month %% 12 == i)
  NTemp <- cbind(NTemp, dummy)
}

#Making months column (there's one observation every month for 17 years)
NMonth <- rep(1, 17)
for( i in 2:12 ) {
  NMonth <- c(NMonth, rep(i, 17))
}

#Put them together
NMitchell <- cbind(NMonth, NTemp)
```

My question is this:

Is there a simpler / better way of doing this? A lot of the time I've made short function like this recently I've found out there's a nice one line thing you can do e.g. using sapply. I can't see how I'd use an apply function here, but is there anything nice any of you can see?

Thanks.

Comment: Just `Mitchell[order(Mitchell$Month %% 12),]`?

Comment: Yes, that works wonderfully thanks (I'm still very new to R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add one more column for the NMonth (1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc), and sort on (NMonth, Month) so that observations with the same month are sorted by year.  Is this what you want?

```
Mitchell$NMonth <- (Mitchell$Month %% 12)+1
NMitchell <- Mitchell[with(Mitchell,order(NMonth,Month)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the expressive `dplyr` package

```
data(Mitchell, package = "alr4")
library(dplyr)
Mitchell %>%
  mutate(month = Month %% 12 + 1) %>%
  select(month, Temp) %>%
  arrange(month)
```